# How do I evade the result of infinity when I am doing 1000^1000 in a calculation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, encryption, output, rsa, infinity

I am trying to make an RSA like encryption program. Therefore I need to perform a calculation 1069^1099. The problem is that the result of that calculation is infinity according to Javascript. Is there any way around this problem?

```
var n = 23 * 83;
var e = 87;
var d = 1099;
var m = 1069;
var m = m**d % n; //Result NaN because m**d = infinity
```

Comment: Note that `(a * b) % c` == `((a % c) * (b % c)) % c`...

Comment: You are looking for [modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation)

Comment: or a library that works with big numbers, like https://github.com/rauschma/strint or https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just developing a toy RSA cipher that doesn't use huge prime numbers, then you can implement [modular exponentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) as follows:

```
function modexp(base, exponent, modulus) {
    var result = 1;
    while (exponent) {
        if (exponent & 1) {
            result = (result * base) % modulus;
        }
        base = (base * base) % modulus;
        exponent >>= 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

The Wikipedia article has a detailed description, but what it basically does is split *x<sup>e</sup>* into the product of *x* raised to the power of numbers corresponding to each set bit in the binary representation of *e*. For example, *x*<sup>13</sup> == *x*<sup>8</sup> × *x*<sup>4</sup> × *x*<sup>1</sup> (because 13<sub>10</sub> == 1101<sub>2</sub>). This can be calculated efficiently by squaring *x* at each step, and applying the modulus after each calculation so that the numbers don't get too large.

As others have said, you'll need a [big number library](http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+big+number+library) to handle real-world RSA keys.

Comment: Thanks, i made something like that myself too :)

Answer (score 0):

I use bignum to circumvent the limits of large numbers in js.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/bignum

Your code would look something like this:

```
var result = bignum(m).pow(d).mod(n)
// or more consicely
var result = bignum(m).powm(d, n)
```

Comment: You don't need bignum to do compute 1000 to the 1000 mod 1069.

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Comment: The javascript number type is an [IEEE 754 binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). It has 53 bits of precision. n=1069 uses 11 bits (actually 10.06 bits). Using the [binary modular exponentiation algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Right-to-left_binary_method) no intermediate product need ever be larger than n*n, a 21 bit number. Thus the intermediate results and final answer fit easily in a javascript number. Or, just look at the other answer.